# How do I make an edit text view work like a search bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, search, textview, android-jetpack

I don't want to use a Search View or a third party library to implement a search bar. I want to use an edit text view that I can customize thorougly to implement my search bar. How do I go about doing that? I remember reading some answer or article where they set an attribute to an edit text to make it function like a search view. something like:

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:name="search view"/>
```

**Update:**
[A diagram to explain the architecture of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyKEe.jpg)
What I was trying to do above has many other complications so now I am trying a different method. Here's what I wanna do. I want to use the search view as an action view for a menu item. My app is following the single activity pattern and my activity has two children fragments. The menu and the toolbar don't need to be inflated differently in different fragments as they look the same in both the fragments. But the problem is, the search view is supposed to behave differently in different fragments. So in the first fragment, when onQuerySubmit() is called, I want to use a navigation action and open the second fragment and pass in the `query` to the second fragment using safe args. In the second fragment, however, I want to show the search results based on the query that was passed in by the first fragment or the queries the user might input once they have reached the second fragment since both the fragments are supposed to have the search view (and that's why it was inflated in the activity).

What I could do is to get a reference to the parent activity from both the fragments and use `onQueryTextSubmit()` but for that I would have to use `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in both the fragments which resets the state of the toolbar and upon configuration change or fragment transaction, the search view is collapsed and the data is lost. I can't use `onQueryTextSubmit()` on either of the fragment's `onViewCreated()` since the activity's `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is called after `onCreate()` and if I get a reference to the search view menu item from the activity and try to do anything to it from either of the Fragment's `onViewCreated()` I would get a null pointer exception.

After getting a reference to the inflated menu or one of the menu items (the search view in this case), is there a way I can work with it after the activity's `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is called but without having to use `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` and `onCreateOptionsMenu()` in either of the fragments.

[Here's](https://www.github.com/sbeve72/JADA) a link to the repo of my app for more information if needed]

Comment: you want to just search the value from a drop down and select it or u want to save it too?

Comment: also say kotlin or java

Comment: @vishalN Kotlin preferably but Java would work. Also I wnt to save it too.

Answer (score 0):

exactly it cant be done with EditText but with **AutoCompleteTextview**

```
 <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/search_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="search view"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
        android:completionHint="@string/message"
        android:inputType="text"
        />
```

The above xml code creates an Autocomplete Text input field where when you type 1 word it will start showing matches in the drop-down (since completeionThreshold ="1"). This is not enough you also have to add an Adapter to it from which it will display the searched item in the drop down.
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView
check this link for the program part.

Comment: Please check out the update, I have changed my uproach. Thank you for reply tho.

Answer (score 0):

you can use native SearchView

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

More look at : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView

Comment: Like I said, it's not customizable enough so I don't want to use a search view.

Comment: Please check out the update i have changed my approach.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically you can do something like that in kotlin, (I use bindingView but you can get id tho):

```
binding.YOUREDITTEXT.addTextChangedListener(onTextChanged = { text, _, _, _ ->
        filteredList = contacts.filter { it.firstName.contains(text.toString(), true) }
        val myAdapter = PersonAdapter(this, filteredList as ArrayList<Person>)
        binding.YOURLIST.adapter = myAdapter
        
    })
```

then for the the on setOnItemClickListener :

```
        if (filteredList != null) {
            intent.putExtra("contact", filteredList!![position])
        } else {
            intent.putExtra("contact", contacts[position])
        }
```

this solved my problem